# can not push files to remote host

Tags: git, docker, gogs

I have started a container (git service) using this command...

```
# Create local directory for volume.
$ mkdir -p /var/gogs

# Use `docker run` for the first time.
$ docker run --name=gogs -p 10022:22 -p 10080:3000 -v /var/gogs:/data gogs/gogs
```

I am able to start the git service and can check the newly created repository from browser...

http://52.201.82.96:10080/shantanuo/testme

But when I follow these steps, I get an error (permission denied):

```
touch README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin http://localhost:3000/shantanuo/testme.git
git push -u origin master
```

Is it a docker issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the docker port 3000 is linked to 10080 of the host machine, use this...

```
git remote add origin http://52.201.82.96:10080/shantanuo/testme.git
```

Answer (score 0):

u should define the volume datapoint,
e.g.

```
mkdir -p /var/gogs
VOLUME["/var/gogs"]
```